# NodeJS express-session, if cookie path is set, cookie doesn't save

Tags: express, web, cookies

I have a web page with passport login and express session.

Everything works but the cookie and I noticed what was the problem ( if I define the path of the cookie, the cookie doesn't add to the domain. )

If anyone knows why it happens please tell me.

(session store: connect-mongo 4.6.0)

```
app.use(session({  
  secret: 'secret',  
  store: Store.create({  
    mongoUrl: 'myMongoURL',  
    dbName: 'db-sessions'  
  }),  
  cookie: {  
    path: '/menu',  
    domain: 'mydomain.com',  
    maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24,
  },  
  resave: false,  
  saveUninitialized: false,  

}))
```

Comment: When you add a path, that cookie will ONLY be sent to the server for a request to that specific path.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you very much, now I understand. I was thinking that the path was the one from the requester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a path to the cookie, that cookie will ONLY be sent to the server for a request to that specific path.

So, only a request for the `/menu` path sent to your server will include that specific cookie.  A request to your server for any other path will not include that cookie.  The client is only sending the cookie with requests that match that specific path.

Note that a path in the cookie of `/menu` will match a request to `/menu` and also `/menu/somethingelse`.